# Obtain intermediate points of a given path

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[-latex] (-1,0) -- (6,0) node[right]{$x$};
\draw[-latex] (0,-1) -- (0,3.5) node[above]{$y$};
\coordinate (A) at (0.5,0.5);
\coordinate (B) at (5,3);

\path[name path=curva,draw,red,thick] (A) to[out=0,in=180] (2,2.5) to [out=0,in=180] (3,1) to [out=0,in=180] (4,2) to [out=0,in=180] (5,3);

\fill[red] (A) circle (1.5pt);
\fill[red] (B) circle (1.5pt);

\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

whose output is the following:

[image]

I want to obtain several points of the `path`defined above. For example, points from 10%, 20%, 30% of A-B. How can I do this?

Comment: I'm not quite sure if that's what you want but with the `decorations.markings` library and the [`mark` key](https://tikz.dev/library-decorations#pgf/decoration/mark) you can can do stuff along the whole path. Say `mark = at position 0.1 with \coordinate (p);` gives you coordinate `p` at 10% of the path length between `A` and `B` if you used on the `curva` path. (Doesn't need to be a coordinate, you can directly place a drawing there, of course.)

Comment: but my path has several defined points, not only A and B

Comment: Yes, but the decoration can act on the whole path containing all four curves.